# spring-web: get @RequestBody as a JSONObject

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-web

I've been hitting a block while using the spring-web library (installed via Gradle, so dependencies are installed).

I know that i can use `@RequestBody` to input POSTed request contents and convert it into a POJO via the Jackson Unmarshaller like so:

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/action", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
public MyResponsePOJO post(@RequestBody MyRequestPOJO request){
    // ...
```

However, I want to take the POSTed contents (JSON) as a Java `JSONObject`.

I've tried using `@RequestBody` with `JSONObject` but I get HTTP 400 errors.

There are a few methods that come to my mind to work around this:

1. Input the `@RequestBody` as a `String` and parse it to a `JSONObject` using Jackson. (This involves me manually converting the request content, which I feel Jackson or Spring should do automatically)
2. Add a `BufferedReader` parameter to my function and parse the request content with Jackson. (Again, this involves manual conversion)
3. Input the `@RequestBody` as a `Map<String, String>` (However, my request isn't entirely String-valued)
4. Input the `@RequestBody` as a `Map<String, Object>` (This causes issues like Unchecked Casts)
5. Second Last Resort: Create a `Request` POJO with a property as `Map<String, Object>` (This causes the same issues as 4. above)
6. Last Resort: Create POJOs for every expected input (Quite infeasible, as there are a lot of expected inputs)

So, is there any *automatic* way by which I can get the `@RequestBody` as a `JSONObject` or should I just create POJOs?

Thanks all :)

Comment: The simple answer would be Create POJOs... The `@RequestBody` doesn't know about JSON, XML or whatever format you decide to use. If you really want it, and tie everything to JSON only you could write your own `HttpMessageConverter` to support the `JSONObject` however I would suggest using POJOs, we live in een OO world after all.

Comment: @M.Deinum i agree, but in the project i'm working on, there are a large enough amount of inputs to consider POJOs as infeasible. That's why I'm trying to find a JSONObject solution

Comment: So instead of strongly typed objects, you want to parse properties and strings manually. That is hardly more feasible then maintaining proper objects. But as mentioned you could, I would however strongly advice against it as you are basically ignore OO that way (imho).

Comment: @M.Deinum i'll consider creating POJOs. but i'll leave the question open for answers just in case someone else needs it for an odd reason

Comment: The answer is already in my first comment, write your own `HttpMessageConverter` to do that.